# How can I set statement_timeout for an individual migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I'd like to set postgres `statement_timeout` for an individual migration. I can't seem to be able to do this. Here's my experiment:

```rb
def change
  execute <<~SQL
    SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 1; -- ms

    -- this does not cause a timeout which is expected, because pg
    -- only applies the timeout to the next protocol message / statement,
    -- and rails sends everthing inside execute in the same statement
    select pg_sleep(1); -- seconds
  SQL

  # if uncommented, this DOES cause a timeout, which is expected
  # execute <<~SQL
  #   select pg_sleep(1); -- seconds
  # SQL

  # this does not cause a timeout, which is unexpected
  remove_column :foos, :bar

  # we do get here, which is unexpected
  raise "we finished"
end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Something else is happening here as:
```test(5432)=> begin ;
BEGIN
test(5432)=> SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 1; select pg_sleep(1);
SET
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```
What does the Postgres log show when you run your code?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there is nothing in the log when i have query log off (no errors). do you want to see the query log?

Comment: I'm starting to suspect my "problem" is that dropping the column takes less than 1ms. I'm exploring that here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269251/how-can-i-see-execution-time-of-an-alter-table-statement

Comment: @JohnBachir After the edits you made to your code example (removing `disable_ddl_transaction!`), it does not really makes sense now. Your first call to `pg_sleep` _does_ raise a timeout. Sending the `SET` and `pg_sleep` within the same `execute` call makes no difference. Also, it’s likely your `remove_column` is just quick enough that PG completes it before it even gets a chance to check if it exceeds any timeout you have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After turning on [log_duration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269278/12659) and doing more investigation, I think I am coming to the conclusion that postgres just doesn't consider droping the column to take more than 1ms, even when something like this is logged:

```
statement: ALTER TABLE "foos" DROP COLUMN "bar"
duration: 1.171 ms
duration: 0.068 ms
duration: 0.328 ms
```

But with the below recipe,

1. I am able to get another type of query to fail due to statement timeout
2. I am able to get drop column to fail due to lock timeout (while holding lock in a psql session)

```rb
class TimeoutTest < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def change
    execute <<~SQL
      SET statement_timeout = 1; -- ms
      SET lock_timeout = 1; -- ms
    SQL

    # I can't get this to fail due to a statement timeout, but does fail due to lock timeout
    # interestingly, if both timeouts are set, it will be statement timeout which happens first. not
    # sure if this is a pg bug, or if calculating the lock timeout somehow increases the overall statement
    # overhead
    remove_column :foos, :bar

    # With 100k of rows of test data, this does fail the statement timeout
    Foo.unscoped.update_all(bar: 5)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume your question is about setting `statement_timeout` for an *individual statement* within your migration (not for an *individual migration*).

You can achieve this by using [Postgres’s `SET` instead of `SET LOCAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set.html#id-1.9.3.173.6).

```rb
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  # Disables BEGIN/COMMIT around migration. SET LOCAL will have no effect.
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    # Applies to the current database session, until changed or reset.
    execute <<~SQL
      SET statement_timeout = '1s';
    SQL

    # Will raise `ActiveRecord::QueryCanceled`.
    execute <<~SQL
      SELECT pg_sleep(2);
    SQL

    # Resets (disables) timeout.
    execute <<~SQL
      SET statement_timeout = DEFAULT;
    SQL

    # Will not raise.
    execute <<~SQL
      SELECT pg_sleep(2);
    SQL
  end
end
```

Note that you *could* use `SET LOCAL` if you don’t call `disable_ddl_transaction!`. Combining both doesn’t work because `SET LOCAL` outside a transaction block has no effect. It logs:

`WARNING:  SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks`

PS: Your call to `disable_ddl_transaction!` would raise `NoMethodError`. It should be before the `def change` definition.

Comment: Thanks @rafbm - I tried this, which I think is compatible with your recommendations, and the timeout did not work https://gist.github.com/jjb/349d2ea7fc685a0159e06fc9e62b3af1

Comment: @JohnBachir Have you tested with plain `pg_sleep` calls? I wouldn’t be surprised if your simple `remove_column` was quick enough that PG completes it before it even gets a chance to check if it exceeds any timeout you have set.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the lower level `exec_query` or go even lower with `execute_and_clear` or lower still with `exec_no_cache`.